# Add multiple labels in oxyplot chart without letting them overwrite the linear axis values

Tags: c#, oxyplot

I'm trying to add labels for the x and y axes, but the label is actually overwriting the linearaxis values.

[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbg43.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the AxisTitleDistance attribute. Either in the XAML or in code.

```
model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, AxisTitleDistance = 25});
model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, AxisTitleDistance = 25});
```

Comment: I solved the problem using the AxisDistance attribute. The AxisTitleDistance doesn't work because i have to move the label instead of the title.